# Infinite currying with typescript

Tags: typescript, currying

I made following code implementing joining of path by infinite currying.

```js
function joinPath(): string
function joinPath(a: string): typeof joinPath
function joinPath(a?: string): string | typeof joinPath {
  if (a === undefined) { return '' }
  const func = (b?: string) => {
    if (b === undefined) { return a }
    return joinPath(`${a}/${b}`)
  }

  return func as typeof joinPath
}


console.log(joinPath('www.github.com')()) // www.github.com
console.log(joinPath('www.github.com')('react')) // www.github.com/react
```

The result of `joinPath` is not literal type but string type.

e.g. `joinPath('facebook')(): string // not 'facebook'`

How can I make the result literal type? It seems I have to use generic type, but I could not find the way to work.

I tried to make the result type as literal using generic type but it did not work.

Comment: Yes, I can remove lodash and `react` has to be a `string` because this function is made for url path.

Comment: Anyway, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NDDolN) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes it was the solution that I wanted. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to keep track of the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the string being built up, you're going to need the type of `joinPath` to itself be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in that type.  And since calling the resulting function with another string is going to have the effect of modifying that string, you will want the type of `joinPath` to be a recursive generic type.  It's easiest to do that with a named interface like:

```
interface JoinPath<T extends string> {
  (): T;
  <U extends string>(a: U): JoinPath<`${T}/${U}`>
}
```

So `JoinPath<T>` is holding onto the string literal type `T`.  If you call it with no arguments you get `T` as a result. Otherwise, if you call it with an argument of generic type `U` constrained to `string`, you get `` JoinPath<`${T}/${U}`> `` as a result, where we've used a [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) to represent the concatenation of `T` with `U`.

And now you can annotate [the overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) call signatures as follows:

```
function joinPath(): ""
function joinPath<U extends string>(a: U): JoinPath<U>
function joinPath(a?: string) {
  if (a === undefined) { return '' }
  const func = (b?: string) => {
    if (b === undefined) { return a }
    return joinPath(`${a}/${b}`)
  }
  return func
}
```

So `joinPath()` returns the empty string ""`, otherwise` joinPath(a)`returns`JoinPath`.

---

Let's test it out:

```
const w = joinPath();
// const w: ""
console.log(w); // ""

const f = joinPath('www.github.com');
// const f: JoinPath<"www.github.com">

const x = f();
// const x: "www.github.com"
console.log(x); // www.github.com

const g = f("react");
// const g: JoinPath<"www.github.com/react">

const y = g();
// const y: "www.github.com/react"
console.log(y); //  "www.github.com/react" 

const h = g("foobar");
// const h: JoinPath<"www.github.com/react/foobar">
const z = h();
// const z: "www.github.com/react/foobar"
console.log(z); // "www.github.com/react/foobar"
```

Looks good.  In all situations the type of the variables and the values of the variables agree.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)